# Sync Production Postgres Database to Laptop - One Way

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am running PostgreSQL 11 on my Windows Laptop and would like to sync with our production database on a (semi) regular basis and then test a number of queries and view creation without running the risk of damaging the master data.  The master data set is pretty big and I work at remote offices over a WAN so a simple one-way compare and replace if necessary option would work best.  Most of the utilities I have found are *nix based, so not good for me.   Need some form of 'add in' to PGSQL or a Windows application. Any help appreciated.  Cheers Bill

Comment: The easiest way is probably `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` - however that is not a "delta" load. It's a flush & fill and would require copying the whole dump over the network. I don't know if that is feasible with your WAN connection

Comment: The ideal way would be to restore from an existing backup, or hook into streaming replication.

Comment: Navicat for PostgreSQL (commercial version) https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-postgresql might help.

Comment: Is the master server also on Windows?